# Create Win32 Window using C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, winapi, win32gui

so im currently making an custom rendered but I cannot understand how to make a win32 window on c#.
I need one because its more optimized, way less messier and suports DirectX accelerated rendering than winforms and wpf.

What i already tried:

- Searching on google, no valid/useful anwsers for the problem thought.

Thank you for your time, ItsRedly

Comment: You can use a library such as SlimDX if you want DirectX support for C#.

Comment: With Windows Forms being pretty much a managed interface over native `HWND`'s it's rather inconclusive to want native `HWND`'s but not Windows Forms. You seem to have misidentified the problem you wish to solve.

Comment: This open source project here https://github.com/aelyo-softworks/Wice does that (no dependency on WPF, on Winforms only for diagnostics, uses Direct Composition, DirectX, Direct2D), creating code is here https://github.com/aelyo-softworks/Wice/blob/main/Wice/Window.cs#L1767 with all interop definitions, but what you want to do is nothing but a quick & dirty task. If you want DirectX + Win32 + C#, the most simple and official way is to head for WinUI3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/

Answer (score 2):

Look it up on msdn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program), then pinvoke all the functions.

Comment: This link is for C++ programming, not C#.

Comment: It still works thought. I just need to p-invoke all the functions and rewrite the code for c#

Comment: @topsail you are supposed to pinvoke the c++ methods...

Comment: Win32 window, Win32 api. There is [a project](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara) which contains various .NET assemblies that contain P/Invoke functions, interfaces, enums and structures from Windows libraries.

Comment: And there's also an official P/Invoke Source Generator called [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32).

Comment: Yes, but i think most of us like writing the code ourselfs